# Summation of a sequence

Tags: r

If n(1) = 1 ,n(2) = 5, n(3) = 13, n(4) = 25, ...
I am using a for loop for summation of these terms
`1 + (1*4 - 4) + (2*4 - 4) + (3*4 - 4) + ..`

This is the function I am using with a for loop:

```
shapeArea <- function(n) {

     terms <- as.numeric(1)
     for(i in 1:n){
       terms <- append(terms, (i*4 - 4)) 
     }
    sum(terms)
}
```

This works fine (as shown here):

```
> shapeArea(3)
[1] 13
> shapeArea(2)
[1] 5
> shapeArea(4)
[1] 25
```

Yet I was also thinking how can I do this without saving the terms of the series in numeric vector `terms`.  In other words is there a way to find summations of terms without saving them in a vector first.  Or is this the efficient way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this `2n^2-2n+1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `shapeArea` function to a one-liner

```
shapeArea <- function(num) {
    1 + sum(seq(num) * 4) - (4 * num)
}  

shapeArea(1)
#[1] 1
shapeArea(2)
#[1] 5
shapeArea(3)
#[1] 13
shapeArea(4)
#[1] 25
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know if I would have to find an expression for the series like you did, otherwise store my sequence in a vector.

Comment: @Bhail If there is a formula to calculate, you would more often than not find an expression to solve it. So no need to store the results in a vector.

Comment: Thanks that is very keen and valuable comment, I can think back to calculus and vaguely recall what you said.